# Reading child list of a parent list

Tags: .net, linq

I am trying to write a linq query.basically the requirement is this
I have this parent list which contains a list of applicant 
Applicant=(john,mary,sam......)
Inside each applicant there are multiple there are multiple.attributes represented by an object
For example: john has his credit bureau information through an object collection called bureau which contains bureau score,quality score,customer score and so on.Inside bureau.

Now the requirement is I want to.loop through all applicant.go inside bereau of each applicant and then see.if the bureau score of that applicant is zero or not.Remember
Bureau score is inside the object collection bureau which is inside the parent list of applicant
Bureau score is  a string that is how it's passed from.the vendor and I don't want a null exceptions if a.node dosent exist

Code Sample: Lets say I have an Employee Collection.That Employee Collection has a further Bureau Collection and inside Bureau you have a collection of attributes one of which is Bureau score. 
I wrote down this

```
 var item = Employee
              .Where(x => x.Bureau != null)
              .SelectMany(b => b.Bureau)
              .Select(bs => bs.BureauScore != null &&
                            int.TryParse(bs.BureauScore, out result));
```

Reason I used a try parse is because by default BureauScore is a string. All I need to find out is if there is an integer value inside BureauScore or not.

This code works for me I did this after I posted but any comments to further make it concise would be appreciated.

Comment: Hi Aamir please post the code of the models you just mentioned

Comment: please share code in your question

Comment: @yonBav  -
I wrote down this 
 var item = Employee.Where(x => x.Bureau != null).SelectMany(b => b.Bureau).Select(bs => bs.BureauScore != null && int.TryParse(bs.BureauScore, out result));

Reason I used a try parse is because by default BureauScore is a string. All I need to find out is if there is an integer value inside BureauScore or not. 

This code works for me I did this after I posted but any comments to further make it concise would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use this as well:

```
Employee.Where(x => x.Bureau?.Any(y => y.BureauScore != null)
```

The sign of "?." means if Bureau == null then the value will be null, and it wont throw an exception.

I'm not sure which one is more readable, but if i Understood right what you wanted to do this should work as well.